# How to merge a git repository into a branch of another repository

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository XXX. 
I want to merge into a branch of repository YYY.
After the merge, YYY should have a branch named XXX.
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you literally mean to `merge` branches, or are you wanting to add a totally new branch to YYY from XXX?

Answer (score 1):

The following may work.

From repository YYY, run the following:

```
git remote add XXX https://github.com/YourUsername/XXX.git
git fetch XXX
```

Now, you should have branches like `XXX/master` and any other branches that were in repository XXX, prefixed with `XXX/`.

If you want to merge, for example, `XXX/master` and your current branch on YYY into a new branch called `merged-from-XXX`, you can do this:

```
git checkout -b merged-from-XXX
git pull XXX master
```

You will be prompted to make a merge commit and resolve any conflicts if necessary.